# realtime p2p streams with dht

Tags: streaming, p2p, real-time, dht

Is it possible to stream realtime in a dht network like kademlia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype uses a DHT.

So, yes you can stream over a p2p network that uses a DHT.

EDIT:

See "The Feasibility of DHT-based Streaming Multicast": http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~sbirrer/nwu/publications/mascots05feasibility.pdf